# Avoid default constructor for member variable

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have a class with a member variable of another class:

```
class MeasurementUnit {
private:
    MeasurementMultiplier _multiplier;
```

Actually I would not need a default constructor for `MeasurementMultiplier`, because actually I will initialize with parameters `MeasurementMultiplier(a,b,c)`, and I would - but can't directly:

```
C2864: 'MeasurementUnit::_multiplier' :
only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
```

So I need the default constructor, without it does not compile `error: C2512: 'MeasurementUnit' : no appropriate default constructor available`

Can I avoid needing the default constructor?

Comment: Use an initializer list or get a compiler that supports C++11 in-class member initialization.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/

Comment: You may need to reword this question?  I for one didn't understand it.

Comment: You could give default parameter values to some other constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all constructors of your class `MeasurementUnit`, you need to initialize the member variable `_multiplier` in the initializer list. Example:

```
MeasurementUnit::MeasurementUnit()
  : _multiplier(1,2,3)
{}
```

Comment: Sorry,I do not get it. By doing so you have a default constructor,this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @HorstWalter: In this case I don't get your question. The *example* I gave refers to the (default) constructor of `MeasurementUnit` to avoid the need for a default constructor of `MeasurementMultiplier`. If this is not what you wanted, please edit and clarify the question.

Comment: @HorstWalter: And I just realized *my* mistake of mixing up the member variable's name and its type. I edited the answer accordingly, sorry for the confusion it might have caused.

Answer (score 1):

Use MIL - Member Initialization List
[MIL](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list&ei=KEJCUfmzM4GftAbVwIHQDQ&usg=AFQjCNGKHJWkHUw40zqaeQW0pptgwS0_HA&bvm=bv.43287494,d.Yms)